# Does solcjs replace solc? Is there a wrapper for the differences?

Tags: solc, solcjs

It at least appears to me that "solc" (the executable) doesn't exist anymore. Installing "solc" with nmp results in a command-line tool called solcjs ... fine, but they seem to have slightly different interfaces. And there are tools that wrap solc/solcjs that are broken by this.
Geth's abigen appears to be one of them. I get the following when I try to use it:

```
$ abigen --sol=Foo.sol --pkg=main --out=foo.go
Fatal: Failed to build Solidity contract: solc: exit status 1
Invalid option selected, must specify either --bin or --abi
```

Which is true! But it looks like I'm faced with either creating/finding a solc wrapper or updating abigen (which is also fine, but I'm looking for direction so I don't waste too much time.)

Or am I not looking hard enough for `solc`?

Comment: Thankfully Google has indexed this question, so now when I search for "solc solcjs wrapper" I can be reminded that nobody knows.  jjj/kkk

_I_ should write a wrapper. I just wonder if there's a less-stupid option.